# parseInt % and px problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parseint

```
<div style="left: 100%"></div>

parseInt($("div").css("left"), 10);
```

When I try to get value of `left`, some browsers give result in pixels, some in %.

Here is an **example** http://jsfiddle.net/WTt4s/1/

Google Chrome gives percent value, IE9 gives pixels instead.

How do I get the same value in all browsers (px or %)?

Comment: have you checked the actual text value of `top`? Is it still in percent or have the browsers converted it to pixels? If it is still in percent, what happens if you strip the '%' character before doing the parseInt? -- `$("div").css("top").replace('%','')`

Comment: What's the output of `alert($("div").css("top"))` in place of the `parseInt`?

Comment: it does not seem like a parseInt problem but browser related behavior

Comment: Please provide a test case, preferably using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @Spudley you are true, browser convers value to pixels. I get 100px instead of 100% without parseInt.

Comment: added a test case on jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one `parseInt($("div")[0].style.top, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.offset().top` or `.position().top` instead